# make a healthcheck page for ASP.NET MVC 4 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am making a healthcheck page for my ASP.NET MVC 4 application. When website admin hit this page,  (like  http//: myapp.com/healthcheck), this page should check database availability and application running status. DB up and running status I have checked by opening a db connection and check whether there is any exception or not. Application running status (like www.myapp.com) , i have checked by sending a HttpWebRequest request to it.

For this , I have added new healthcheck controller/ model/ cshtml page. It is working as expected.

The problem is that, this new healthcheck page is in same application, so if my application is down (such as due to wrong routing or wrong configuration in web.config or by any other means), then my this health check page will also not load. Can you please suggest a better solution/architecture/work around to solve this problem?

Comment: You can create a separate application for health-check. From your main application, you can expose couple of json/xml endpoints to serve the health-check data, and call them from the other application. (I'm not saying this is the best approach, I'd look for forward for good answers.)

Comment: Can you please clarify problem - so far it sounds perfect behavior - if site is down your page is failing too...

Comment: Thanks all. Yes , I think I should make a different application for health check which should check status of my main application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This health checkup module should be a different virtual directory/website. If you host this in the same server wherever original application is running then health checkup module should be running under a separate application pool. Connect original application either through javascript/ajax or from server using HttpClient/HttpWebRequest.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.